# Function to replace file input type="file" button works but asks for file twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile 1.7.1 for a button replacement of native `input type="file"`.

Code works but forces a second request on the browse/open file bit.

What am I missing?

Same behavior on Chrome and FF (have not tried elsewhere).

```
<div id="fileInputButton"  data-role="button" data-icon="gear" style="width:150px;margin:0 auto; text-align:center">Import</div>

<div id="filename"></div>

<input style="opacity:0;" id="the_real_file_input" name="foobar" type="file">

 <script>
  $('#fileInputButton').click(function() {
    $('#the_real_file_input').click();
  });

  $('input[type=file]').bind('change', function() {
    var str = "";
    str = $(this).val();
    $("#filename").text(str);
  }).change();
 </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: Works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pg3Qf/ until JQuery Mobile is applied. (Thanks @wirey !)

FINAL UPDATE: This fixes the double trigger issue:

```
$('#fileInputButton').click(function(e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     $('#the_real_file_input').click();
 });
```

And, this fixes the "C:\fakepath\" issue in Chrome and Safari:

```
str = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
```

Comment: works fine for me in firefox/chrome/IE http://jsfiddle.net/pg3Qf/

Comment: @wirey Thanks. Does it break for you when you apply JQM in the fiddle? Works for me too without JQM.

Comment: Ah ok I see now.  I didn't apply JQM..  It does trigger twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why but using stopImmediatePropagation stops it from triggering twice.  It doesn't look like the event would be bubbling up to anything

```
$('#fileInputButton').click(function(e) {
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     console.log('triggered');
     $('#the_real_file_input').click();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pg3Qf/3/

Comment: Thanks! I'm OK with the mystery as long as it works. Now, i need to figure out why `$("#filename").text(str);` prepends "C:\fakepath\" to the file name in Chrome and Safari but not in FF. I'm aware that it's a browser security thing so will probably need to just write something to strip it out.

Comment: This fixes the C:\fakepath\" issue: `str = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');`